# Spring Boot - configuration class naming help required

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm quite new to **Spring Boot**.  I have to admit to being a little lost in the plethora of options that are available for configuration;

```
@EnableBlah
extend BlahAdapter
extend BlahConfigurer
extend BlahConfigurerAdapter
implements (and sometimes extend) BlahCustomizer
```

In the [JavaDocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/api/) I've found some clues;

- **Adapter**s are generally an implementation of a **Configurer** with empty methods allowing subclasses to override chosen methods.
- **Customizer**s are either interfaces or abstract classes ready to be implemented

Is there a *rule of thumb* which could help me discern what the name of the particular configuration class is likely to be for a particular set of circumstances?

For example, when might I expect to be looking for a **Configurer** or **Adapter** rather than a **Customizer**?

Comment: good one, I don't know if there is a rule in spring and i don't think; in general in java I would find as best practice to add that information in the class name suffix (BlahController for instance); someone may also argue that the package name can be enough...